# Fitting an Image to Screen on Rotation iPhone / iPad?

Tags: iphone

I have been playing around with one of the iPhone examples from Apple' web site (ScrollViewSuite) . I am trying to tweak it a bit so that when I rotate the the iPad the image will fit into the screen in landscape mode vertical. I have been successful in getting the image to rotate, but the image is larger than the height of the landscape screen, so the bottom is below the screen. I would like to image to scale to the height of the landscape screen.

I have been playing around with various autoSizingMask attributes without success.

The imageView is called "zoomView" this is the actual image which loads into a scrollView called imageScrollView.

I am trying to achieve the screen to rotate and look like this....  sorry only 1 link allowed new user :(

olsonvox.com/photos/correct.png

However, this is what My screen is looking like.

http://www.olsonvox.com/photos/incorrect.png

I would really appreciate some advice or guidance. Below is the RootViewController.m for the project.

- Blade

  #

  ```
  import "RootViewController.h"

      #define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
      #define ZOOM_STEP 1.5

      #define THUMB_HEIGHT 150
      #define THUMB_V_PADDING 25
      #define THUMB_H_PADDING 25
      #define CREDIT_LABEL_HEIGHT 25

      #define AUTOSCROLL_THRESHOLD 30

      @interface RootViewController (ViewHandlingMethods)
      - (void)toggleThumbView;
      - (void)pickImageNamed:(NSString *)name;
      - (NSArray *)imageNames;
      - (void)createThumbScrollViewIfNecessary;
      - (void)createSlideUpViewIfNecessary;
      @end

      @interface RootViewController (AutoscrollingMethods)
      - (void)maybeAutoscrollForThumb:(ThumbImageView *)thumb;
      - (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;
      - (void)legalizeAutoscrollDistance;
      - (float)autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:(float)proximity;
      @end

      @interface RootViewController (UtilityMethods)
      - (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
      @end


      @implementation RootViewController

      - (void)loadView {
          [super loadView];

          imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view]bounds]];

       // this code makes the image resize to the width and height properly. 
       imageScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

       // TRY SETTNG CENTER HERE SOMEHOW>....


       [imageScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
          [imageScrollView setDelegate:self];
          [imageScrollView setBouncesZoom:YES];
          [[self view] addSubview:imageScrollView];
       [self toggleThumbView];


       // intitializes with the first image.

          [self pickImageNamed:@"lookbook1"];
      }

      - (void)dealloc {
          [imageScrollView release];
          [slideUpView release];
          [thumbScrollView release];
          [super dealloc];
      }

      #pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

      - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
          UIView *view = nil;
          if (scrollView == imageScrollView) {
              view = [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
          }
          return view;
      }

      /************************************** NOTE **************************************/
      /* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
      /* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
      /**********************************************************************************/
      - (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
          [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
          [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
      }

      #pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

      - (void)tapDetectingImageView:(TapDetectingImageView *)view gotSingleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint {
          // Single tap shows or hides drawer of thumbnails.
          [self toggleThumbView];
      }

      - (void)tapDetectingImageView:(TapDetectingImageView *)view gotDoubleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint {
          // double tap zooms in
          float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
          CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:tapPoint];
          [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
      }

      - (void)tapDetectingImageView:(TapDetectingImageView *)view gotTwoFingerTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint {
          // two-finger tap zooms out
          float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
          CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:tapPoint];
          [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
      }

      #pragma mark ThumbImageViewDelegate methods

      - (void)thumbImageViewWasTapped:(ThumbImageView *)tiv {
          [self pickImageNamed:[tiv imageName]];
          [self toggleThumbView];
      }

      - (void)thumbImageViewStartedTracking:(ThumbImageView *)tiv {
          [thumbScrollView bringSubviewToFront:tiv];
      }


      // CONTROLS DRAGGING AND DROPPING THUMBNAILS...

      - (void)thumbImageViewMoved:(ThumbImageView *)draggingThumb {

          // check if we've moved close enough to an edge to autoscroll, or far enough away to stop autoscrolling
          [self maybeAutoscrollForThumb:draggingThumb];

          /* The rest of this method handles the reordering of thumbnails in the thumbScrollView. See  */
          /* ThumbImageView.h and ThumbImageView.m for more information about how this works.          */

          // we'll reorder only if the thumb is overlapping the scroll view
          if (CGRectIntersectsRect([draggingThumb frame], [thumbScrollView bounds])) {        

              BOOL draggingRight = [draggingThumb frame].origin.x > [draggingThumb home].origin.x ? YES : NO;

              /* we're going to shift over all the thumbs who live between the home of the moving thumb */
              /* and the current touch location. A thumb counts as living in this area if the midpoint  */
              /* of its home is contained in the area.                                                  */
              NSMutableArray *thumbsToShift = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

              // get the touch location in the coordinate system of the scroll view
              CGPoint touchLocation = [draggingThumb convertPoint:[draggingThumb touchLocation] toView:thumbScrollView];

              // calculate minimum and maximum boundaries of the affected area
              float minX = draggingRight ? CGRectGetMaxX([draggingThumb home]) : touchLocation.x;
              float maxX = draggingRight ? touchLocation.x : CGRectGetMinX([draggingThumb home]);

              // iterate through thumbnails and see which ones need to move over
              for (ThumbImageView *thumb in [thumbScrollView subviews]) {

                  // skip the thumb being dragged
                  if (thumb == draggingThumb) continue;

                  // skip non-thumb subviews of the scroll view (such as the scroll indicators)
                  if (! [thumb isMemberOfClass:[ThumbImageView class]]) continue;

                  float thumbMidpoint = CGRectGetMidX([thumb home]);
                  if (thumbMidpoint >= minX && thumbMidpoint <= maxX) {
                      [thumbsToShift addObject:thumb];
                  }
              }

              // shift over the other thumbs to make room for the dragging thumb. (if we're dragging right, they shift to the left)
              float otherThumbShift = ([draggingThumb home].size.width + THUMB_H_PADDING) * (draggingRight ? -1 : 1);

              // as we shift over the other thumbs, we'll calculate how much the dragging thumb's home is going to move
              float draggingThumbShift = 0.0;

              // send each of the shifting thumbs to its new home
              for (ThumbImageView *otherThumb in thumbsToShift) {
                  CGRect home = [otherThumb home];
                  home.origin.x += otherThumbShift;
                  [otherThumb setHome:home];
                  [otherThumb goHome];
                  draggingThumbShift += ([otherThumb frame].size.width + THUMB_H_PADDING) * (draggingRight ? 1 : -1);
              }

              // change the home of the dragging thumb, but don't send it there because it's still being dragged
              CGRect home = [draggingThumb home];
              home.origin.x += draggingThumbShift;
              [draggingThumb setHome:home];
          }
      }

      - (void)thumbImageViewStoppedTracking:(ThumbImageView *)tiv {
          // if the user lets go of the thumb image view, stop autoscrolling
          [autoscrollTimer invalidate];
          autoscrollTimer = nil;
      }

      #pragma mark Autoscrolling methods

      - (void)maybeAutoscrollForThumb:(ThumbImageView *)thumb {

          autoscrollDistance = 0;

          // only autoscroll if the thumb is overlapping the thumbScrollView
          if (CGRectIntersectsRect([thumb frame], [thumbScrollView bounds])) {

              CGPoint touchLocation = [thumb convertPoint:[thumb touchLocation] toView:thumbScrollView];
              float distanceFromLeftEdge  = touchLocation.x - CGRectGetMinX([thumbScrollView bounds]);
              float distanceFromRightEdge = CGRectGetMaxX([thumbScrollView bounds]) - touchLocation.x;

              if (distanceFromLeftEdge < AUTOSCROLL_THRESHOLD) {
                  autoscrollDistance = [self autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:distanceFromLeftEdge] * -1; // if scrolling left, distance is negative
              } else if (distanceFromRightEdge < AUTOSCROLL_THRESHOLD) {
                  autoscrollDistance = [self autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:distanceFromRightEdge];
              }        
          }

          // if no autoscrolling, stop and clear timer
          if (autoscrollDistance == 0) {
              [autoscrollTimer invalidate];
              autoscrollTimer = nil;
          } 

          // otherwise create and start timer (if we don't already have a timer going)
          else if (autoscrollTimer == nil) {
              autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0 / 60.0)
                                                                 target:self 
                                                               selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:) 
                                                               userInfo:thumb 
                                                                repeats:YES];
          } 
      }

      - (float)autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:(float)proximity {
          // the scroll distance grows as the proximity to the edge decreases, so that moving the thumb
          // further over results in faster scrolling.
          return ceilf((AUTOSCROLL_THRESHOLD - proximity) / 5.0);
      }

      - (void)legalizeAutoscrollDistance {
          // makes sure the autoscroll distance won't result in scrolling past the content of the scroll view
          float minimumLegalDistance = [thumbScrollView contentOffset].x * -1;
          float maximumLegalDistance = [thumbScrollView contentSize].width - ([thumbScrollView frame].size.width + [thumbScrollView contentOffset].x);
          autoscrollDistance = MAX(autoscrollDistance, minimumLegalDistance);
          autoscrollDistance = MIN(autoscrollDistance, maximumLegalDistance);
      }

      - (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {
          [self legalizeAutoscrollDistance];

          // autoscroll by changing content offset
          CGPoint contentOffset = [thumbScrollView contentOffset];
          contentOffset.x += autoscrollDistance;
          [thumbScrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset];

          // adjust thumb position so it appears to stay still
          ThumbImageView *thumb = (ThumbImageView *)[timer userInfo];
          [thumb moveByOffset:CGPointMake(autoscrollDistance, 0)];
      }

      #pragma mark View handling methods

      - (void)toggleThumbView {
          [self createSlideUpViewIfNecessary]; // no-op if slideUpView has already been created
          CGRect frame = [slideUpView frame];
          if (thumbViewShowing) {
              frame.origin.y = 0;
          } else {
              frame.origin.y = -225;
          }

          [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
          [slideUpView setFrame:frame];
          [UIView commitAnimations];

          thumbViewShowing = !thumbViewShowing;
      }

      - (void)pickImageNamed:(NSString *)name {

          // first remove previous image view, if any
          [[imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG] removeFromSuperview];

          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", name]];
          TapDetectingImageView *zoomView = [[TapDetectingImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


       zoomView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;


          [zoomView setDelegate:self];
          [zoomView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
          [imageScrollView addSubview:zoomView];
          [imageScrollView setContentSize:[zoomView frame].size];
          [zoomView release];

          // choose minimum scale so image width fits screen
          float minScale  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [zoomView frame].size.width;
          [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minScale];
          [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minScale];
          [imageScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
      }

      - (NSArray *)imageNames {

          // the filenames are stored in a plist in the app bundle, so create array by reading this plist
          NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:@"plist"];
          NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
          NSString *error; NSPropertyListFormat format;
          NSArray *imageNames = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                                                 mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                           format:&format
                                                                 errorDescription:&error];
          if (!imageNames) {
              NSLog(@"Failed to read image names. Error: %@", error);
              [error release];
          }

          return imageNames;
      }




      - (void)createSlideUpViewIfNecessary {

          if (!slideUpView) {

              [self createThumbScrollViewIfNecessary];

              CGRect bounds = [[self view] bounds];
              float thumbHeight = [thumbScrollView frame].size.height;
              float labelHeight = CREDIT_LABEL_HEIGHT;

              // create label giving credit for images
              UILabel *creditLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, thumbHeight, bounds.size.width, labelHeight)];

              [creditLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
              [creditLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

       // [creditLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];
       // [creditLabel setText:@"SAMPLE TEXT"];

              [creditLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];        


              // create container view that will hold scroll view and label
              CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -225.00, bounds.size.width+256, thumbHeight + labelHeight);
        slideUpView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
              slideUpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
              [slideUpView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
              [slideUpView setOpaque:NO];
              [slideUpView setAlpha:.75];
              [[self view] addSubview:slideUpView];

              // add subviews to container view
              [slideUpView addSubview:thumbScrollView];
              [slideUpView addSubview:creditLabel];
              [creditLabel release];   



          }    
      }

      - (void)createThumbScrollViewIfNecessary {

          if (!thumbScrollView) {        

              float scrollViewHeight = THUMB_HEIGHT + THUMB_V_PADDING;
              float scrollViewWidth  = [[self view] bounds].size.width;
              thumbScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight)];
              [thumbScrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
              [thumbScrollView setClipsToBounds:NO];

              // now place all the thumb views as subviews of the scroll view 
              // and in the course of doing so calculate the content width
              float xPosition = THUMB_H_PADDING;
              for (NSString *name in [self imageNames]) {
                  UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_thumb.jpg", name]];
                  if (thumbImage) {
                      ThumbImageView *thumbView = [[ThumbImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbImage];
                      [thumbView setDelegate:self];
                      [thumbView setImageName:name];
                      CGRect frame = [thumbView frame];
                      frame.origin.y = THUMB_V_PADDING;
                      frame.origin.x = xPosition;
                      [thumbView setFrame:frame];
                      [thumbView setHome:frame];
                      [thumbScrollView addSubview:thumbView];
                      [thumbView release];
                      xPosition += (frame.size.width + THUMB_H_PADDING);
                  }
              }
              [thumbScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xPosition, scrollViewHeight)];
          }    
      }

      #pragma mark Utility methods

      - (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

          CGRect zoomRect;

          // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
          //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
          //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
          zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
          zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

          // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
          zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
          zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

          return zoomRect;
      }


      #pragma mark -
      #pragma mark Rotation support

      // Ensure that the view controller supports rotation and that the split view can therefore show in both portrait and landscape.
      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return YES;
      }






      @end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up your UIScrollView in a Nib file, make sure it is resizing properly when rotated (Use the Autosizing controls in the Size Inspector in Interface Builder: Both sets of arrows inside the box should be red)

Then use this to rescale when the iPad changes orientation:

```
- (void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
//if your UIImageView is called zoomView use this
CGRect zoomRect=CGRectMake(0,0,zoomView.frame.size.width, zoomView.frame.size.height);
[scrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];}
```

(Sorry about the bad placement of the {} but it wasn't pasting properly as code for some reason)
Hope this helps!